# Избавление от внутренних стилей при анимации jq

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть разметка

```
<div class="tabs">
      <div id="tab1" class="vis">
        <h3>Панель 1</h3>
        <p>Содержимое 1 панели...</p>
        <button type="button" class="next">Далее</button>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="unvis">
        <h3>Панель 2</h3>
        <p>Содержимое 2 панели...</p>
        <div style="height: 366px; background-color: black;"></div>
        <button type="button" class="back">Назад</button>
        <button type="button" class="next">Далее</button>
      </div>
      <div id="tab3" class="unvis">
        <h3>Панель 3</h3>
        <p>Содержимое 3 панели...</p>
        <button type="button" class="back">Назад</button>
        <button type="button" class="next">Далее</button>
      </div>
      <div id="tab4" class="unvis">
        <h3>Панель 4</h3>
        <p>Содержимое 4 панели...</p>
        <button type="button" class="back">Назад</button>
        <button type="button" class="finish">Сохранить</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Использую классы для скрытия и отображения элементов. 
При использовании анимации jq, добавляется внутренний css `display:block || none`

Как этого избежать? или ничего страшного в этом нет?

Comment: Если все работает как надо - ничего страшного нет =) Если смотреть в будущее, то "внутренний css" перекрывает тот, что описан в подключаемых стилях (если !important не указан)